# Using the Jira REST API with cURL to upload .zip file

Tags: rest, curl, jira

So I'm trying to upload a .zip file to Jiras restAPI but I'm getting error 415 unsupported media type.

What I've tried:

```
curl -D- -u $username:$password -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: no-check" -H "Content-Type:application/zip" -F "file=@result.zip" $myURL/rest/api/2/issue/QTC-12/attachments
```

But sadly this gives 415.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to the `-H "Content-Type:application/zip"` I suspect that the Jira API isn't expecting a zip as the content type.

As it is using the `-F` option this is probably a form which is the default content type used by Curl so have you tried removing the zip header and running the command?

Edit:
Just looked at the JIRA API [https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.6.1/#api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/attachments](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.6.1/#api/2/issue/%7BissueIdOrKey%7D/attachments)
And it is of multipart/form-data type.  The example on the API shows no other content type header.

Comment: Thanks man, i added that because i was getting another error at first. But I later fixed that error but kept that content-type. Jeez what a pain that was :D